# how to export ruby on rails app workspace to a different build meachine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I built a web app on a mac M1 using ruby on and now I need to deploy it on a different Linux PC, so how do I export the workspace from my mac M1 to my Linux PC.

Comment: There are a lot of public tutorials available that provide instruction on how to deploy a rails application. I would recommend [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=deploy+rails+application) and picking the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: If it where me I would use github.  Make a git repository attach your app to it, push your code to the git repository and then clone it on your new machine or the machine you want to use it on.

Comment: try dockerizing your app with its dependencies, it will let you achieve portability